# URL rewriting not Working in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, umbraco

I have a URL like this `www.mysubdomain.domain.com/brands/bname.aspx` and I want to rewrite it to `www.mysubdomain.domain.com/bname` I have done some logic like this

```
   <add name="redirect_brands" redirectMode="Permanent" ignoreCase="true"
rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite"
virtualUrl="^/brand/(.*)$" destinationUrl="^/$1" />
```

but this always redirects to home page(/).I am not sure what went wrong..everything looks good to me..Can any one give a me hand on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<add name="redirect_brands" redirect="Application" redirectMode="Permanent" virtualUrl="^~/brand/(.*)" rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite" destinationUrl="/$1" ignoreCase="true" />
```

I think you're missing the ~ in the virtualUrl